# Null Reference Exception on using Adobe3D Reviewer class

Tags: vb.net, adobe

I am new to programming in VB. I am trying to use a built-in interface in the Adobe3DReviewer in my code. I need to use a method of the interface so I am trying to create an object. However, when I try to use the object to access the method I get this error:

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled.Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any suggestions/comments will be greatly appreciated.Here is my code snippet:

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
Dim attVal As New Object
Dim geomItemObject As Adobe3DReviewer.GeomItem
    geomItemObject = Nothing
  attVal = "value"
//The error is thrown at this line.
geomItemObject.AddAttribute("hi", attVal)
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Since you set geomItemObject = Nothing, it will not be found. Can you try to remove this line first?

Comment: @hallie I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you check which class inherits feom GeomItem? or a method that returns a GeomItem?

Answer (score 0):

You set geomItemObject to Nothing, which is causing the exception.  Perhaps you need Dim geomItemObject as New Adobe3DReviewer.GeomItem.

Sorry, can't be more specific but i don't know Adobe3DReviewer.

Comment: I see that GeomItem is an interface.

Comment: Well what class implements the interface?

Comment: @collegian: If GeomItem is an interface it means that the implementation is not there. You migth need to use different method that returns a GeomItem to get your object.

Comment: @hallie:                                                            @Richard:                                                           I am getting confused here. In the object browser GeomItem is mentioned as a class however it shows up as an interface in the code(intellisense). Assuming it to be a class,I tried to use the new keyword but I get this error : 'Adobe3DReviewer.GeomItemClass.Friend Sub New()' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.  Can you tell me what this error means?

Comment: It means that the type can only be accessed by any code within the same assembly.

Comment: @hallie Does this mean that I need to find some other way to use the methods of that class?

Comment: Are sure that the class your trying to use is open to the public? I actually cannot find that library (Adobe3DReviewer) on the net. Is it provided by Adobe? There might be a documentation how to use that library.

Comment: @hallie Yes,GeomItem shows up as a Public Class in the Object Browser within Adobe3DReviewer Namespace under Interop.Adobe3DReviewer.dll assembly. It can be obtained when Adobe 3D Reviewer Object Library(under COM) is added as a reference. However, I believe you need to have Adobe 3D Reviewer installed on your system which you can get once you install the extended version of Adobe.